# Android Fragment Oncreateview Loadanimation

Tags: android, animation, fragment

I created an app, which using InfiniteViewpager by antonyt.

I want to add an Animation on an `Imageview` when my View is created, but my Animation working a few times, not always. Here's the code:

```
public class ColourFragment extends Fragment {


private int identifier;
private String logo;




@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
Bundle args = getArguments();

identifier = args.getInt("identifier");
logo = args.getString("logo");
}

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View V = inflater.inflate(R.layout.radiologok, container, false);
```

The `ImageView` I want to animate.

```
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView)V.findViewById(R.id.radiologovalaszto); 


    ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) V.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
    int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels / 4 * 3;
    int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels / 4 * 3;  


    imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
    imageView.getLayoutParams().height = height;
    imageView.getLayoutParams().width = width;
```

Load Android Query library to get image from the web.

```
   AQuery aq = new AQuery(getActivity());
   AQUtility.setDebug(true);
   aq.hardwareAccelerated11();
```

The image is set.

```
aq.id(imageView).progress(progressBar).image(logo, true, true, width, 0);
```

Here i want to add the `Animation`

```
    Animation pulse = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.pulse);
imageView.startAnimation(pulse);

    Return V;
```

}

Here's my Animation:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shareInterpolator="false" >
<scale
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromXScale="1"
    android:fromYScale="1"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toXScale="0.5"
    android:toYScale="0.5" />
<scale
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromXScale="1"
    android:fromYScale="1"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:startOffset="1000"
    android:toXScale="2"
    android:toYScale="2" />
   </set>
```

I load the view by using a fragmentadapter:

```
 final PagerAdapter adapter = new FragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()) {

                @Override
                public int getCount() {
                return Radiologos.length;
                }

                @Override
                public Fragment getItem(int position) {
                Fragment fragment = new ColourFragment();
                Bundle args = new Bundle();

                args.putString("logo", Radiologos[position]);
                args.putInt("identifier", position);
                fragment.setArguments(args);
                return fragment;
                }
            };
```

Comment: Are you reusing the view ? Is this inside any listview ?

Comment: But Where are you showing this fragment ? in list or Activity or Viewpager, and please post the code where you use it

Comment: Edited my post with the fragmentadapter.

Comment: Your using viewpager so the view is not re-created for the next and previous views(after being created once) only after if you swipe the pages to a few number (+2) ahead or behind only the view is recreated so how many pages do you have in your view pager ??

Comment: 36 + 2, because it's an infinityviewpager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this thing, it might work

**1st** Create a class that holds some static variables so that we can use it later

**StaticVariables.java**

```
public static ArrayList<ImageView> listOfImageViews = new ArrayList<ImageView>();
```

**2nd** Now on the `onCreateView` where you create the `imageview` as usual and now pass it to the static variable that we just created

```
imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
imageView.getLayoutParams().height = height;
imageView.getLayoutParams().width = width;
....
StaticVariable.listOfImageViews.add(imageview);
```

**3rd** Now on the view pager that your using add a pageListener and on the `onPageSelected` add the animation on the `imageview` and start the animation

```
mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onPageSelected  " + arg0);
            //Create your animation
            Animation pulse = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.pulse);
            //Start your animation
            StaticVariable.listOfImageViews.get(arg0).startAnimation(pulse);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {}

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {}
    });
```